# Using Hashtags in CKEditor to Run Real-time MediaWiki Searches

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, ckeditor, mediawiki-api

I'm using CKEditor for my web app and I would like to run searches on the MediaWiki API as soon as a hashtag "#" is entered, i.e. #plants.

What I'm trying to pull are images from the MediaWiki library that can be placed back into the document.

I'm not sure which language I would need to use to do that, JavaScript, JQuery, PHP, Ajax? I would greatly appreciate the help. Thanks.